# Calling OnClick() twice causes OnClick to not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of cells, when a cell is clicked an event is triggered.  I want to add cells dynamically so I will call OnClick again on all rows.  When I call OnClick for the second time, any cells that have OnClick called twice stop firing any events.

The odd thing is at the event of my OnClick function, if I can "Return;" it works, however it throws an error saying "Return" isn't defined

```
function initBox() {
    $(".selectable").on('click', function (event) {

        //if its selected already, unselect it
        if ($(this).hasClass('rowHighlightColor')) {
            $(this).removeClass("rowHighlightColor");
            selectedCellList = null;
        }
        else {
            //unselect previous cell
            if (selectedCellList != null) {
                selectedCellList.removeClass("highlighted");
            }
            selectedCellList = $(this);

            $(this).addClass("rowHighlightColor");
        }
        Return;
    });
}
```

Comment: Please read description before you downvote, I know Return is not defined.  I am saying it's weird that it makes it work

Comment: Have you made any progress with your problem? Add a `console.log` to your function, I'm pretty sure it gets called twice, thus nullifying the "addClass" effect, making you think it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding multiple event handlers to existing cells. This is one reason why I prefer to use just the plain old `.onclick` property.

Anyway, to solve this issue you can either only apply the event to the new cells, or add an attribute to them when you do add an event, then check that attribute before adding the event again.

Answer (score 7):

it needs to be `return` instead of `Return` (capital R)

however, writing `return;` returns `undefined` so you can just omit it.

edit:

you attach the event twice, make sure only to attach it once, else it causes (as you noticed) undesired behaviour like attaching class and immediately removing it again.

The reason why it works with "Return" is that the function is only run once because it throws an error when reaching it.

Use jQuerys `.live()` (or `.on()` for newer versions, as live is deprecated there) to automatically attach the click event to every new row you add. [jQuery live Docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: ya but then it doesn't fire the event the second time. that's the odd thing